# How to stack CSS elements horizontally for websites

Tags: html, css, layout, css-grid, element

I'm building my first real webpage and I'm trying to figure out how to stack the elements on the home screen correctly. I've read and tried similar posts but they don't seem to do what I need. Currently my homepage looks like this (ignore the list at the bottom of the page and subscribe/ login buttons. They are just part of the default theme):
[image]

This was achieved using the following code:
HTML:

```
<div class="desc-pic-parent">
    <div class="homepage-description">
        <div class="homepage-description-header">
            Hi! I'm Lewis Cooper
        </div>
        <div class="homepage-description-text">
            This is a description of me. I will put quite a bit of text here so that I can get a rough idea of what it's going to look like in the final edit of the webpage
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="square-pretend-img"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 1001px) {
    .disc-pic-parent {
        grid-column: 1 / span 3;
        display: grid;
        grid-gap: 4vmin;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
        min-height: 280px;
        border-top: 0;
    }


    .homepage-description{
        text-align: left;
        display: grid;
        grid-gap: 4vmin;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
        min-height: 280px;
        border-top: 0;
    }

    .homepage-description-header{
        font-size: 3rem;
        margin-top: 0;
    }

    .square-pretend-img{
        position: relative;
        height: 20rem;
        width: 20rem;
        background-color: #555;
        grid-column: 2 / span 2;
    }
}
```

My goal is to try and get it to look something like this sketch:
[image: what i want the webpage to look like]

Comment: Do you want the text to flow under the img if there is too much of it to fit in the same, neat, height as you have in your design?

Comment: No ideally I’d want the blue box in the diagram to keep the same width even if it extends lower than the grey box (if that makes sense)

Comment: OK, using grid is fine then. Minor note, you have a typo in your CSS, disc instead of desc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of using a grid for the main layout is fine and will keep your text at a constant width even if it is too long, but you also have put a grid in  your left hand box which isn't the layout your desired image shows. You have also given the img defined dimensions and yet defined column spans for the grid.

This snippet just takes it that you want the img to have the given dimensions so removes the extra grid information.

```css
@media (min-width: 1001px) {
  .desc-pic-parent {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 4vmin;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    min-height: 280px;
    border-top: 0;
  }
  .homepage-description {
    text-align: left;
    min-height: 280px;
    border-top: 0;
  }
  .homepage-description-header {
    font-size: 3rem;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  .square-pretend-img {
    position: relative;
    height: 20rem;
    width: 20rem;
    background-color: #555;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="desc-pic-parent">
  <div class="homepage-description">
    <div class="homepage-description-header">
      Hi! I'm Lewis Cooper
    </div>
    <div class="homepage-description-text">
      This is a description of me. I will put quite a bit of text here so that I can get a rough idea of what it's going to look like in the final edit of the webpage
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="square-pretend-img"></div>
</div>
```

NOTE: you probably want to take some of the styling out of the media query and have it there for all viewport dimensions.

Comment: This works really well! Thanks. The only issue that's showing now is that the whole thing isn't centred. Is that a problem with this part of the code or would it be located elsewhere?

Comment: All good now! I seemed to have fixed it with `justify-items: center;`. Thanks for your help once again

Answer (score 1):

This can be simply achieved using `flexbox`.
Just wrap those two div's inside another `div` and give `display: flex` to that div.

Comment: Could it be done with the desc-pic-parent div or would it need to be wrapped in a new one